# Multiple identical columns in multiple data frames - R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, multiple-columns

I have four `data frames` with one similar column named "Type".

```
df1 <- data.frame(Type = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'))
df2 <- data.frame(Type = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'))
df3 <- data.frame(Type = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'))
df4 <- data.frame(Type = c('A','Z','C','D','E','F'))
```

I would like to check if this column is identical over all `data frames`.

At the moment I'm checking two data frames at a time by using this:

```
as.integer(as.logical(identical(df1$Type, df2$Type)))
```

Which gives me 1 if identical and 0 if not.

I would like to perform a single line such as this:

```
as.integer(as.logical(identical(df1$Type, df2$Type, df3$Type, df4$Type)))
```

But `identical` can only handle 2 columns at once.

I also found this [Testing for multiple identical columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011280/testing-for-multiple-identical-columns-in-r), but this only applies for columns in one `data frame`.

Comment: You could do `length(unique(list(df1, df2, df3, df4))) == 1` assuming the single variable in the data frame shares a common name as in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extract the `Type` column from the dataframes and compare any one element with all of them.

```
list_df <- mget(paste0('df', 1:4))
#Or manually creating a list
#list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

tmp <- lapply(list_df, `[[`, 'Type')
all(sapply(tmp, function(x) all(x == tmp[[1]])))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I changed ```df4``` so all 4 data frames are identical and used your solution
```Reduce(function(x, y) all(x == y), 
       lapply(list(df1, df2, df3, df4), `[[`, 'Type'))```
but it still returns the value ```FALSE```

Comment: Sorry, for messing this up. I hope the update helps. @ConnorUhl . Thanks 27 ϕ 9

Comment: No need to apologize ;) I'm always super thankful for your help!!! @Ronak Shah